# Keras - Extracting Embedding Layer weights when using multiple GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

In my setup I train a dense keras layer where the weights of the layer become image embeddings.  I then take the weights of this layer and do the dot product of this with a set of input vectors.

I want to run this using GPUs, and with 1 GPU it works fine.  However, I have noticed that when following the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus) for multiple GPUs in data parallelism mode, the model summary that appears shows a change in the structure of my network.  It looks like this is because it is "replicating the target model once on each device, and using each replica to process a different fraction of the input data".

**Question:**  When I am extracting the weights from my embedding layer, will it still give me the whole layer, or will I need to extract multiple sets of weights and merge them somehow?